# Multiply a users input on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

- rails 4.1.7
- ruby-2.1.4

I am trying to get an input from the user and save the double of that number. For example if the user enters a 3, I should save a 6.

Pretty simple uhh?! Well, I am getting it wrong.

**Controller**

```
def new
  @calculate                = Calculate.new  
end

def create
 @calculate  = Calculate.new(calculate_params)
 @calculate.number = @calculate.number * 2

 @calculate.save
end

def set_calculate
  @calculate = Calculate.find(params[:id])
end

def calculate_params
  params.require(:calculate).permit(:number)
end
```

But the actual value saved is the original input. Going back to the example is a 3 when it should be a 6. What am I doing wrong, seems a very simple thing. I just upgraded to rails 4.1 from rails 3.2, is there something different on the way that the controller gets executed?

Comment: What does the Calculate class look like?

Comment: I strongly advice to set double number in model